# I am doing a self join in spark sql. Does it make sense to cache this table?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am doing a self join in spark sql. Does it make sense to cache the self joined table?
There are 2 tables that I am using for self join

for example

select * from Table A
inner join TableB
inner join TableA
Inner join TableB

Both TableA and TableB are 2gb and 1gb respectively.

Comment: caching is useful to save intermediate computations for faster access, as you can retrieve direct result instead of re-doing the previous computations.